# Is it possible to present more than one UIAlertController on screen at a time?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, uialertcontroller

Currently working fine with `UIAlertView` but i'm going to remove all `UIAlertView` object as its now not longer available from iOS8 (means its deprecated in iOS8).
In my app i'm calling one web service using NSTimer in background with some time interval. So if web service give success event then it will give alert for success event.
But at that time if `UIAlertController` already present and i'm trying to present another `UIAlertController` then i'm getting warning :[4103:88382] Warning: `Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f90fbd579f0>  on <ActionViewController: 0x7f90fc03e600> which is already presenting`
So in my case more than one alert may present at any time. How can i handle this with `UIAlertController`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Dismiss the 1st one before showing the next one.

Comment: Thanks for reply, that is not possible in my case, because my first alert is showing downloading or upload progress, so i can't dismiss it.

Comment: Then present the 2nd alert from the 1st alert.

Comment: Yes thanks, i had think about this too but alert may be more than two then? how can i create object of UIAlertController dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

While generally not recommended, you can spawn a second UIWindow with an empty view controller as its root ([UIVIewController new]) and then present the UIAlertController from this new window's rootViewController.  Be warned that spawning extra windows can cause issues with auto-rotation. Consider refactoring your download progress UI to use something less intrusive such as https://github.com/mwkoelb/MWKProgressIndicator.